# Create Table in Excel Worksheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet, listobject

I have this code below that will auto select a range.
Does anyone know how I can add code to create a table to the selected range?

Thanks!

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when first column has value on last row and first row has a value in the last column

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("D9")

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
  sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the following Excel VBA code snippet to add the `Table` object corresponding to selected `Range`:

```
Dim objTable As ListObject
Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
```

You can also apply optional styling to the added `Table` object like shown below:

```
objTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
```

More details available at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823155.aspx

Hope this will help.

Comment: Fantastic from both of you - saved me about 2 hours faffing around trying to find a solution.  Stole both your idea's added it to a Save to SharePoint piece of code so I can now use the excel sheet in power Automate (Flow)

Comment: @RobertW081171 Can you please share how you added code to be able to use excel sheet in Power Automate?

Comment: Please add your definition for xlSrcRange and Selection