# How to apply Table Style to current selection

Tags: excel, vba

I got a doubt/problem with VBA while creating a macro.
Basically I want to apply a Table "Style" to my current selection which is the following:

```
Range("A1:J1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The macro I recorded then applies a Table with the following code:

```
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$J$319"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table4"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight15"
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
```

Now what I am concerned about is in the really first line, the Range("$A$1:$J$319") which is clearly the interval I selected with the first three lines of code. Is there a way to make this range something like this?

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("Selection"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table4"
```

I want something like this because my interval could change in the future (by being 50 lines less or more) and I don't want the table to be applied to empty or more lines...

I hope I explained myself clearly! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are looking for simply `Selection`, instead of your `Range("Selection")`. Please be advised however to avoid using select. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba for a 'how to'

Comment: Thank you very much Ouroboros1, it was simpler than I thought and now I feel also silly for having asked such a thing! I'll also check the link you gave me!

Comment: Incidentally, when you start reusing this code within the same worksheet, you will likely run into a different error, namely that you are trying to create a Table named `Table4`, when the sheet already has one. To avoid this potential error, have a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874319/create-table-in-excel-worksheet-using-vba and change the first 2 lines of your code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the further info, but I already solved that even before by using a simple and ugly Selection.Clean ahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.CurrentRegion` can be used to reference all the connected cells (a.k.a. contiguous cells).

It would be best to set a reference to the ListObject because it has many built in properties that allow us to reference it's different parts.

```
Dim ListObject As ListObject
Set ListObject = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
With ListObject
    .Name = "Table4"
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight15"
End With

With ListObject.Range
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function to add the listobject.

You pass the top left corner of your future table to the function - e.g. `activesheet.range("A1")`.

The function then uses - as TinMan - explained `CurrentRegion` to add the listobject.

If you pass a name and or TableStyle to the function they will be applied.
If TableName already exists - an counter will be added to the name.

If the Style doesn't exists the error will be ignored.

```vb
Public Function addListobject(rgTopLeftCorner As Range, _
    Optional TableName As String, Optional TableStyle As String) As ListObject
    
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = rgTopLeftCorner.Parent

Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rgTopLeftCorner.CurrentRegion)

With lo
    
    If LenB(TableName) > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        lo.Name = TableName
        If Err <> 0 Then
            'this will handle the case that supplied TableName is already in use
            Dim i As Long, TableNameNew As String
            Do
                Err.Clear
                i = i + 1
                TableNameNew = TableName & "_" & i
                lo.Name = TableNameNew
            Loop Until Err = 0
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    

    If LenB(TableStyle) > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next    'in case style does not exist
        lo.TableStyle = TableStyle
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

End With

Set addListobject = lo
 
End Function
```

You can call this function like this:

```
Sub test()

Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = addListobject(Selection, "test")
Debug.Print lo.Name

Set lo = addListobject(Selection.Offset(, 5), "test")
Debug.Print lo.Name 'will return test_1

Set lo = addListobject(Selection.Offset(, 10), "test")
Debug.Print lo.Name 'will return test_2

End Sub
```

I am pretty sure that you don't need the

```
With ListObject.Range
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    ...
```

part - esp. if you set the table style. This is presumably an artefact from macro recording ...